# extract text every line and check in regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Hi I have the following 2 documents amongst many in the form of a list.

Document 1:

```
 contact
 TomGonsalves
 985664774
 6560,m.d avenue.

  harrydsouza
  7676764
  543,gt,road.
```

Document 2 in the same python list:

```
  contact
  richard peterson
  4563565
  87,td street,Ny.
```

Here both the above text documents(1 and 2) are part of the same. In the text, I need to extract the 1st line after contact,i.e the name. However in Document-1 there are 2 names which I need to extract and just the names.

I need to write a regular expression to fetch the needful and the output should look like

```
     Names from Document 1 =[tomgonsalves,harrydsouza]
     names from document-2=[richard peterson]
```

Can someone please help me with the reGex script in python 3 for this.There are many docs in the same list which may have different number of names in its contact. I just need to extract the names alone(be it 1 or multiple)

Comment: Honestly, I might prefer just iterating the file line by line and implementing some simple parsing logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Read the `txt` file line-by-line. For each line check if it has only alphabets with `isalpha()` function of string.

```
In [309]: with open('ff.txt') as f: ## ff.txt is the file you shared
     ...:     for i in f:
     ...:         i = re.sub('\n','',i)
     ...:         if i.isalpha():
     ...:             if not i == 'contact':
     ...:                 print(i)

TomGonsalves
harrydsouza
```

You can do this for each file you have.

Answer (score 0):

Although this should be preferred to be attacked by simple text parsing but just in case you want a regex solution, you may use this regex,

```
(?:^\s*[a-zA-Z]+\s*|(\n\s*){2})([\w ]+)
```

[Here is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mc442B/1)

Let me know if this works for you, else please provide more sample input so I can further refine my regex to match your precise input.